# Setting connectionstring in EF for Database first design

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a EF Model generated from a existing database.

BL using the EF model is called from a legacy application which doesn't have a configuration file and i couldn't add the EF Entity connection string.

Trying to figure out a way to add a connection string. I added the following code to the constructor of the Entity class.. When running this implementation i get this error :

**Message = "Keyword not supported: 'metadata'."**

If i remove the MetaData from the connection string then i get this error :

**Code generated using the T4 templates for Database First and Model First development may not work correctly if used in Code First mode. To continue using Database First or Model First ensure that the Entity Framework connection string is specified in the config file of executing application. To use these classes, that were generated from Database First or Model First, with Code First add any additional configuration using attributes or the DbModelBuilder API and then remove the code that throws this exception.**

Code:

```
    public partial class TestQEntities : DbContext
        {

        public TestQEntities(string nameOrConnectionString)
            {
                this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = nameOrConnectionString;
            }

    }



       _context = new TestQEntities(GetConnectionString());

      private static string GetConnectionString()
            {
                var scsb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
                    {
                        DataSource = "(local)",
                        InitialCatalog = "DB",
                        IntegratedSecurity = true
                    };


                var builder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder
                    {
                        Metadata = `enter code here`"res://*/ROModel.csdl|res://*/ROModel.ssdl|res://*/ROModel.msl",
                        Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient",
                        ProviderConnectionString = scsb.ConnectionString
                    };
                     return builder.ToString() + ";App=EntityFramework";
            }
```